# Store split value into separate list python

Tags: python

I want to separate this list into two different list. The pattern that I saw the fruit is the number `1.` always followed by fruit, while animal placed between whitespace except the last one.

```
text = ['1.banana dog 2.apple cat 3.grape tiger 4.orange snake', '1.watermelon hamster 2.pineapple fox 3.coconut lizard']
```

The output will look like this

```
fruit1
['banana apple grape orange']
fruit2
['watermelon pineapple coconut']
animal
['dog cat tiger snake']
animal2
['hamster fox lizard']
```

```
animal=[]
fruit=[]
regex = r"\d+\."
for i in text:
re.match(regex, i):
        element = re.split(regex, i)
        fruit.extend(element)
```

Are there any simpler tips to make the output looks like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to find the relevant parts.

```
texts = ['1.banana dog 2.apple cat 3.grape tiger 4.orange snake', '1.watermelon hamster 2.pineapple fox 3.coconut lizard']
fruits = []
animals = []
for text in texts:
    fruit, animal =  zip(*re.findall('\d+\.(\S+)\s+(\S+)', text))
    fruits.append(fruit)
    animals.append(animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ['1.banana dog 2.apple cat 3.grape tiger 4.orange snake']
textlist = text[0].split()
fruitlist = []
animallist = []
for word in textlist:
    if "." in word:
        fruitlist.append(word.split(".")[1])
    else:
        animallist.append(word)
fruit = " ".join(fruitlist)
animal= " ".join(animallist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sampling the list at regular intervals and `map()`:

```py
text = ['1.banana dog 2.apple cat 3.grape tiger 4.orange snake']
words = text[0].split()
fruit = [' '.join(list(map(lambda x: x[2:], words[0:][::2])))]
animal = [' '.join(words[1:][::2])]
```